# How to link to a Google drive file?

Tags: google-drive-api

This link will access a file in the world of Amazon.

https://prd-tnm.s3.amazonaws.com/StagedProducts/Maps/USTopo/PDF/AL/AL_Alabaster_20201219_TM_geo.pdf

Is there an equivalent for linking to files in Google drive? I want to be able to use a static link to a file that I put in Google Drive from my web site's HTML code.

I made several efforts at finding a valid address for my files. None have been useful.

Comment: Have you tried sharing the file through the web interface?

Comment: Yes I have. I want to move my data from my ISP to somewhere else that cost less. I plan to keep my HTML with my ISP.